# Extracting a table from a mysql.sql dump file

Tags: sql, mysql, linux, scripting

I have a products table in a mysql.sql file. I wish to extract that one table and place it in it's own file. How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 25):

I found [this nice solution](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mydumpsplitter-extract-tables-from-mysql-dump-shell-script), you have to download [this script](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/mysqldumpsplitter.sh.txt) (script copied bellow) on your server and type

```
$> ./MyDumpSplitter.sh yourfile.sql your_table_name
```

This will extract your table into your_table_name.sql

---

*Optionnal*

Now you can rename it using this type of command

```
$> sed -i 's/`your_table_name`/`your_table_name2`/g' your_table_name.sql
```

And re-injecting it with

```
mysql> source your_table_name.sql;
```

**MyDumpSplitter.sh**

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# http://kedar.nitty-witty.com
#SPLIT DUMP FILE INTO INDIVIDUAL TABLE DUMPS
# Text color variables
txtund=$(tput sgr 0 1)    # Underline
txtbld=$(tput bold)       # Bold
txtred=$(tput setaf 1)    # Red
txtgrn=$(tput setaf 2)    # Green
txtylw=$(tput setaf 3)    # Yellow
txtblu=$(tput setaf 4)    # Blue
txtpur=$(tput setaf 5)    # Purple
txtcyn=$(tput setaf 6)    # Cyan
txtwht=$(tput setaf 7)    # White
txtrst=$(tput sgr0)       # Text reset

TARGET_DIR="."
DUMP_FILE=$1
TABLE_COUNT=0

if [ $# = 0 ]; then
        echo "${txtbld}${txtred}Usage: sh MyDumpSplitter.sh DUMP-FILE-NAME${txtrst} -- Extract all tables as a separate file from dump."
        echo "${txtbld}${txtred}       sh MyDumpSplitter.sh DUMP-FILE-NAME TABLE-NAME ${txtrst} -- Extract single table from dump."
        echo "${txtbld}${txtred}       sh MyDumpSplitter.sh DUMP-FILE-NAME -S TABLE-NAME-REGEXP ${txtrst} -- Extract tables from dump for specified regular expression."
        exit;
elif [ $# = 1 ]; then
        #Loop for each tablename found in provided dumpfile
        for tablename in $(grep "Table structure for table " $1 | awk -F"\`" {'print $2'})
        do
                #Extract table specific dump to tablename.sql
                sed -n "/^-- Table structure for table \`$tablename\`/,/^-- Table structure for table/p" $1 > $TARGET_DIR/$tablename.sql
                TABLE_COUNT=$((TABLE_COUNT+1))
        done;
elif [ $# = 2  ]; then
        for tablename in $(grep -E "Table structure for table \`$2\`" $1| awk -F"\`" {'print $2'})
        do
                echo "Extracting $tablename..."
                #Extract table specific dump to tablename.sql
                sed -n "/^-- Table structure for table \`$tablename\`/,/^-- Table structure for table/p" $1 > $TARGET_DIR/$tablename.sql
                TABLE_COUNT=$((TABLE_COUNT+1))
        done;
elif [ $# = 3  ]; then

        if [ $2 = "-S" ]; then
                for tablename in $(grep -E "Table structure for table \`$3" $1| awk -F"\`" {'print $2'})
                do
                        echo "Extracting $tablename..."
                        #Extract table specific dump to tablename.sql
                        sed -n "/^-- Table structure for table \`$tablename\`/,/^-- Table structure for table/p" $1 > $TARGET_DIR/$tablename.sql
                        TABLE_COUNT=$((TABLE_COUNT+1))
                done;
        else
                echo "${txtbld}${txtred} Please provide proper parameters. ${txtrst}";
        fi
fi

#Summary
echo "${txtbld}$TABLE_COUNT Table extracted from $DUMP_FILE at $TARGET_DIR${txtrst}"
```

Comment: be careful: with extracting a single table from a full dump, the 'SET statements' at the beginning of a dump get lost, for example: SET NAMES utf8; - so you might import an utf8 table and get scrambled data because the client uses a wrong encoding! same problem with all other solutions....

Comment: That's correct, thank you for this information

Answer (score 3):

I ran into that problem a while ago and wrote a Perl script. It worked well, but it was an older version of MySQL.  Call it like:
`extract.pl -table=TABLENAME mysqldumpfile.sql > recovered_table.sql`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -s -wnl
#extract a single table from a mysql dump
BEGIN {
    $table or warn
    "Usage: $0 -table=TABLE_TO_EXTRACT mysqldumpfile.sql"
    and exit 1;
}

/^DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `$table`/ .. /^UNLOCK TABLES;$/ and print;
```

Answer (score 3):

simply you can run stream editor for filtering and transforming text command like below:

```
$ sed -n -e '/CREATE TABLE.*products/,/CREATE TABLE/p' mysql.sql > products.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I know of no tool to parse raw mySQL dump files this way.

Either copy+paste it (potentially cumbersome) or import it into a temporary database, drop everything else, and dump the table back into a file.

Comment: There would be no reason to drop everything else, you can mysqldump individual tables

Comment: @stew good point. @OP here's how: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tables

Answer (score 0):

If the dump was done with the extended insert syntax, then the actual table data will be done as a single line within the dump file:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (field, ...) VALUES (data, ...), (data, ...), (etc..)
```

which you could simply grep out. Extracting the actual table definition will be harder, though it SHOULD be immediately above the data line. Don't have access to a proper shell at the moment, but going off the top of my head, something like this might do the trick (in pseudo-code):

```
# retrieve line # that data insertion for the wanted table occurs on
DATALINE=`grep -l 'INSERT INTO tablename' dumpfile.sql`

# limiting ourselves to the part of the file up to the data line, find the line number
# of the last CREATE TABLE, which SHOULD be the one creating the table for the data
CREATELINE=`head -$DATALINE|grep -l 'CREATE TABLE'|tail -1|awk '{"print $1"}'`
```

The you can extract the creation DDL with judicious head/tail and the line numbers we just retrieved:

```
CREATE=`head -$CREATELINE dumpfile.sql|tail -$($CREATELINE - $DATALINE - 1)`
```

bear in mind that I'm going off the top of my head on this, so it's almost guaranteed to not work, but should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract a database you could use:

```
sed -n '/^-- Current Database: `dbname`/,/^-- Current Database: `/p' dumpfile > dbname.sql 2>error
```

For example:

```
sed -n '/^-- Current Database: `blogs`/,/^-- Current Database: `/p' dump.sql > blogs.sql 2>error
```